# What exactly does the service function in nusoap do?

Tags: php, nusoap

Can you please tell me what exactly I can achieve with these two lines:

```
$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : "";
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
```

And why do I get the error: **error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document** when I replace "" with a String variable?

Comment: http_raw_post_data has been officially deprecated and should not be used anymore. if you want the raw post data, then read it from `php://input`.

Comment: I kept on reading this quite a few times. However, I'm more interested in the second line. What happens with the raw post data when I call the service method of the server with it as parameter?